# Start Ruby on Rails server after GUI login

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-buster, ruby, lxsession

I've spent most of the day trying to launch two commands after login of the GUI on Raspberry OS. I am trying to run a Ruby on Rails server after logging into the GUI (not on boot). The commands I would like to run are:

**~/.xsessionrc**

```
#!/bin/bash
. /home/pi/.rvm/scripts/rvm
cd /home/pi/base/ && rails s -b 10.3.141.1 -p 3000 -d &
```

I have been trying to do this using `.profile`, `.bash_profile`, `.bashrc`, `.xsession`, `.xinitrc` but it's proving impossible and I haven't got further than breaking my installation. I've also had a go at the `.desktop` and `autostart` options and followed various articles and Q&As online. Also tried saving it into a separate script and running that, they all work as I expect from the command line when triggered but the server isn't running automatically after GUI login. The closest I've got is the server running automatically once I start a shell from within the GUI.

**I think I should be editing the `xsession` files as these are run by `lightdm` after logging in via the GUI? But when I do the GUI breaks and just returns me to the login password screen after each attempt.**

Despite a lot of time, I don't seem much closer to the solution - from experience this normally means I've misunderstood something fundamental!

Any help would be amazing

Many thanks

Comment: Can you do this manually?  If so what commands do you run and when do you run those commands?

Comment: I can run the two commands in my question manually, or `source ~/.xsessionrc`, in both cases the rails server will start as expected. I get the following error in `~/.xsession-errors`: `/etc/X11/Xsession: 3: /home/pi/.xsessionrc: rails: not found`. I have updated my question so that it reflects my `.xsessionrc` file

Comment: Do "which rails" and replace && rails with the result.

Comment: You're amazing! Finally got there. I also had to switch `/bin/` to `/wrappers/` in the path given by `which rails` as per the [accepted answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26247926/how-to-solve-usr-bin-env-ruby-executable-hooks-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: It would be useful if you answer your question as a guide for others who have a similar problems.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**With Joan's help the solution is to refer to the absolute path of `rails` rather than rely on `rvm`.**

`which rails` - provides an absolute path, in my case `/home/pi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/bin/rails`. You then need to replace `bin` with `wrappers` as per this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26247926/how-to-solve-usr-bin-env-ruby-executable-hooks-no-such-file-or-directory).

You can add your command to the file `.xsessionrc` in your home directory, this is run after logging into the GUI. This can be created if it does not exist. The command below will open up a text editor (`nano`) and create it as required:

```
nano ~/.xsessionrc
```

The contents of the file should be:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd [FULL_PATH_TO_DIRECTORY] && [PATH_TO_RAILS] s -b 10.3.141.1 -p 3000 -d &
```

Where:

- [PATH_TO_RAILS] = /home/pi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/wrappers/rails
- [FULL_PATH_TO_DIRECTORY] = /home/pi/...
- `-b 10.3.141.1` - binds the server to specific ip address, this is
  optional.
- `-p 3000` - designates the port that rails should use,
  again optional
- `-d` - runs the server as a daemon, this is important
  if you're running it in the background
- `&` - ensures that the process
  of booting up continues, and they do not wait for the server to end
  it's process